# Display menu categories and lists all menus under each menu categories and return json data

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following tables

categories and menus. A category can have many menus example rice is a category that has many menus under it. I want to list all categories with their appropriate menu under each category and return json in php using pdo. Below is an example of what I mean

**Soups** 
Booze Wings
Suya Wings
Booze Wings

**Appetizer**
Hot Dogs
Chinese Stir-fried Rice
Fried Rice

Below is the json format how I want it to diaplay

```
"categoryHeading": "Appetizer",
    "menu": [
        {
            "restaurant_name": "METRO CAFE",
            "category_name": "Appetizer",
            "id": 156,
            "restaurant_id": 10,
            "category_id": 1,
            "food_name": "Abacha",
            "price": "300.00",
            "quantity": 12,
            "menu_type": "All day",
            "created_at": "2020-10-28 04:31:50",
            "updated_at": "2020-10-28 04:31:50",
            "image_url": "/storage/foodmenuimages/foodmenimage956871603859510.jpeg",
            "is_active": 1,
            "description": null,
            "month": "October",
            "year": "2020",
            "chopsrestaurant_id": null,
            "is_featured": 0,
            "sub_heading_title": null
        },
        {
            "restaurant_name": "METRO CAFE",
            "category_name": "Appetizer",
            "id": 101,
            "restaurant_id": 10,
            "category_id": 1,
            "food_name": "Avocado Ring Salad",
            "price": "3200.00",
            "quantity": 1,
            "menu_type": "All day",
            "created_at": "2020-09-27 23:56:27",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-27 23:56:27",
            "image_url": "/storage/foodmenuimages/foodmenimage856971601232987.jpg",
            "is_active": 1,
            "description": null,
            "month": "September",
            "year": "2020",
            "chopsrestaurant_id": null,
            "is_featured": 0,
            "sub_heading_title": null
        },
        {
            "restaurant_name": "METRO CAFE",
            "category_name": "Appetizer",
            "id": 88,
            "restaurant_id": 10,
            "category_id": 1,
            "food_name": "Beef Burger",
            "price": "2300.00",
            "quantity": 1,
            "menu_type": "All day",
            "created_at": "2020-09-27 23:07:09",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-27 23:07:09",
            "image_url": "/storage/foodmenuimages/foodmenimage765981601230029.jpg",
            "is_active": 1,
            "description": null,
            "month": "September",
            "year": "2020",
            "chopsrestaurant_id": null,
            "is_featured": 0,
            "sub_heading_title": null
        },
        {
            "restaurant_name": "METRO CAFE",
            "category_name": "Appetizer",
            "id": 90,
            "restaurant_id": 10,
            "category_id": 1,
            "food_name": "Beef Quesadilla",
            "price": "2200.00",
            "quantity": 1,
            "menu_type": "All day",
            "created_at": "2020-09-27 23:10:48",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-27 23:10:48",
            "image_url": "/storage/foodmenuimages/foodmenimage659871601230248.jpg",
            "is_active": 1,
            "description": null,
            "month": "September",
            "year": "2020",
            "chopsrestaurant_id": null,
            "is_featured": 0,
            "sub_heading_title": null
        },

"categoryHeading": "Soup",
        {
            "restaurant_name": "METRO CAFE",
            "category_name": "Soup",
            "id": 111,
            "restaurant_id": 10,
            "category_id": 1,
            "food_name": "Bowl chicken with Assorted Vegi",
            "price": "4100.00",
            "quantity": 1,
            "menu_type": "All day",
            "created_at": "2020-09-28 17:54:50",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-28 17:54:50",
            "image_url": "/storage/foodmenuimages/foodmenimage957681601297690.jpg",
            "is_active": 1,
            "description": null,
            "month": "September",
            "year": "2020",
            "chopsrestaurant_id": null,
            "is_featured": 0,
            "sub_heading_title": null
        },
        {
            "restaurant_name": "METRO CAFE",
            "category_name": "Soups ",
            "id": 83,
            "restaurant_id": 10,
            "category_id": 3,
            "food_name": "Buffalo Wings",
            "price": "1600.00",
            "quantity": 1,
            "menu_type": "All day",
            "created_at": "2020-09-27 22:33:25",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-27 22:33:25",
            "image_url": "/storage/foodmenuimages/foodmenimage596781601228005.jpg",
            "is_active": 1,
            "description": null,
            "month": "September",
            "year": "2020",
            "chopsrestaurant_id": null,
            "is_featured": 0,
            "sub_heading_title": null
        },
        {
            "restaurant_name": "METRO CAFE",
            "category_name": "Appetizer",
            "id": 79,
            "restaurant_id": 10,
            "category_id": 1,
            "food_name": "Butterfly Prawns",
            "price": "3200.00",
            "quantity": 1,
            "menu_type": "All day",
            "created_at": "2020-09-27 22:23:16",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-27 22:23:16",
            "image_url": "/storage/foodmenuimages/foodmenimage698751601227396.jpg",
            "is_active": 1,
            "description": null,
            "month": "September",
            "year": "2020",
            "chopsrestaurant_id": null,
            "is_featured": 0,
            "sub_heading_title": null
        },
        {
            "restaurant_name": "METRO CAFE",
            "category_name": "Appetizer",
            "id": 87,
            "restaurant_id": 10,
            "category_id": 1,
            "food_name": "Chicken Burger",
            "price": "2300.00",
            "quantity": 1,
            "menu_type": "All day",
            "created_at": "2020-09-27 23:02:39",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-27 23:02:39",
            "image_url": "/storage/foodmenuimages/foodmenimage679851601229759.png",
            "is_active": 1,
            "description": null,
            "month": "September",
            "year": "2020",
            "chopsrestaurant_id": null,
            "is_featured": 0,
            "sub_heading_title": null
        },
        {
            "restaurant_name": "METRO CAFE",
            "category_name": "Appetizer",
            "id": 99,
            "restaurant_id": 10,
            "category_id": 1,
            "food_name": "Chicken Mushroom Soup",
            "price": "1600.00",
            "quantity": 1,
            "menu_type": "All day",
            "created_at": "2020-09-27 23:45:21",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-27 23:45:21",
            "image_url": "/storage/foodmenuimages/foodmenimage985671601232321.jpg",
            "is_active": 1,
            "description": null,
            "month": "September",
            "year": "2020",
            "chopsrestaurant_id": null,
            "is_featured": 0,
            "sub_heading_title": null
        },
        {
            "restaurant_name": "METRO CAFE",
            "category_name": "Appetizer",
            "id": 97,
            "restaurant_id": 10,
            "category_id": 1,
            "food_name": "Chicken Noodle Soup",
            "price": "1900.00",
            "quantity": 1,
            "menu_type": "All day",
            "created_at": "2020-09-27 23:44:02",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-27 23:44:02",
            "image_url": "/storage/foodmenuimages/foodmenimage659781601232242.jpg",
            "is_active": 1,
            "description": null,
            "month": "September",
            "year": "2020",
            "chopsrestaurant_id": null,
            "is_featured": 0,
            "sub_heading_title": null
        },
        {
            "restaurant_name": "METRO CAFE",
            "category_name": "Appetizer",
            "id": 91,
            "restaurant_id": 10,
            "category_id": 1,
            "food_name": "Chicken Quesadilla",
            "price": "2200.00",
            "quantity": 1,
            "menu_type": "All day",
            "created_at": "2020-09-27 23:11:12",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-27 23:11:12",
            "image_url": "/storage/foodmenuimages/foodmenimage768591601230272.jpg",
            "is_active": 1,
            "description": null,
            "month": "September",
            "year": "2020",
            "chopsrestaurant_id": null,
            "is_featured": 0,
            "sub_heading_title": null
        },
        {
            "restaurant_name": "METRO CAFE",
            "category_name": "Soups ",
            "id": 81,
            "restaurant_id": 10,
            "category_id": 3,
            "food_name": "Chicken Springroll",
            "price": "1600.00",
            "quantity": 1,
            "menu_type": "All day",
            "created_at": "2020-09-27 22:26:52",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-27 22:26:52",
            "image_url": "/storage/foodmenuimages/foodmenimage869751601227612.jpg",
            "is_active": 1,
            "description": null,
            "month": "September",
            "year": "2020",
            "chopsrestaurant_id": null,
            "is_featured": 0,
            "sub_heading_title": null
        },
        {
            "restaurant_name": "METRO CAFE",
            "category_name": "Appetizer",
            "id": 89,
            "restaurant_id": 10,
            "category_id": 1,
            "food_name": "Chicken Wrap",
            "price": "2200.00",
            "quantity": 1,
            "menu_type": "All day",
            "created_at": "2020-09-27 23:08:39",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-27 23:08:39",
            "image_url": "/storage/foodmenuimages/foodmenimage859671601230119.jpg",
            "is_active": 1,
            "description": null,
            "month": "September",
            "year": "2020",
            "chopsrestaurant_id": null,
            "is_featured": 0,
            "sub_heading_title": null
        },


PHP Codes

 public static function getMenuByRestaurantId($id)
    {
        $selectStatment = \DB::getPdo()->prepare("SELECT r.restaurant_name, c.category_name, m.* from menus as m
        inner join restaurants as r on r.id = m.restaurant_id inner join categories as c on c.id = m.category_id where m.restaurant_id = :restaurant_id order by m.food_name asc");

        $selectStatment->bindValue(':restaurant_id', $id, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $selectStatment->execute();

        $results = $selectStatment->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        return $results;

    }
```

JSON I am trying to return

```
 $menu = DTO::getMenuByRestaurantId($id);
        foreach($menu as $m)
        {
            $heading = $m->category_name;
        }
        return response()->json(["categoryHeading"=>$heading, "menu" =>$menu], 200);
```

Comment: Inside a JSON array, you can't have a key:value alone in the space. Only values, or JSON objects are allowed.

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the sql